# Share a single date amongst Spark nodes

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like to run a spark job that outputs to some directory that contains the day at which the job started. Is there a way to share a single date object (joda.time for example) in all spark nodes, so no matter what node outputs what pipe, they all output to the same dir structure?

Comment: If you know the value of date before job starts you can just use variable in driver program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is

> Is there a way to share a single date object (joda.time for example)
>   in all spark nodes

then naturally the answer is "broadcast the object"

if the real question is how do I specify path of output, then, really you do not need to broadcast the path. You can just say rdd.saveAsFile(/path) and the function will automatically dump each partition in a single file (like part000 or so). Of course, all worker nodes must have access to the location specified by "path" variable, so in a real cluster it has to be HDFS or S3 or NFS or likes.

From documentation:

> saveAsTextFile(path)
>
> Write the elements of the dataset as a text file (or set of text
>   files) in a given directory in the local filesystem, HDFS or any other
>   Hadoop-supported file system. Spark will call toString on each element
>   to convert it to a line of text in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create the object in your driver program (as a `val`) and close over it where you need it. It should be copied over to the worker nodes to be used as you need.